# Objc visible string enum but not RawRepresentable

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, rawrepresentable

I want to use enum that is visible both in objective C and Swift but not conform to protocol RawRepresentable.

1. I tried to have an enum of string both visible in Objc and Swift thus I use

   `typedef NSString *myEnum NS_TYPED_ENUM;`
2. I tried to take advantage of the myEnum(rawValue: ) -> myEnum? function but I found the enumType has automatically conform to

   `public struct myEnum : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
       public init(rawValue: String)
   }`

My question is how to create enum that is visiable in Objc and Swift but not conform to this protocol? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: All ObjC enums are raw representable, because they're just a very thin layer over the raw values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swift Language Enhancements
>
> ... Swift enums can now be exported to Objective-C using the @objc
> attribute. @objc enums must declare an integer raw type, and cannot be
> generic or use associated values. Because Objective-C enums are not
> namespaced, enum cases are imported into Objective-C as the
> concatenation of the enum name and case name.

Above From [Xcode 6.4 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW26)

---

For this purpose you define the values in Objective-C, you can use the `NS_TYPED_ENUM` macro to import constants in Swift
For example:
**.h file**

```
typedef NSString *const ProgrammingLanguage NS_TYPED_ENUM;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageSwift;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageObjectiveC;
```

**.m file**

```
ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageSwift = @"Swift";
ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageObjectiveC = @"ObjectiveC";
```

In Swift, this is imported as a struct as such:

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage: RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable {
    typealias RawValue = String

    init(rawValue: RawValue)
    var rawValue: RawValue { get }

    static var swift: ProgrammingLanguage { get }
    static var objectiveC: ProgrammingLanguage { get }
}
```

Although the type is not bridged as an enum, it feels very similar to one when using it in Swift code.

You can read more about this technique in the "**Interacting with C APIs**" of the [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift#2984801)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, the above NS_TYPED_ENUM will be converted as the following struct but my point is that the init(rawValue: RawValue) was very weird since the protocol https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable define the init as fallible. Not sure why it becomes non-failible in this case...

Comment: Since your `NS_TYPED_ENUM` is converted as above mentioned struct, which proves your initial question is answered. and so for about `init(rawValue: RawValue)` its init is bailable or non-bailable you can ask it in another question. as i said earlier your initial question has been answered, so will you proceed my answer as correct answer while marking tick marking it. After that make another question as i said, so that we could reply that accordingly. Thanks